# Firefox downloads page instead of running it (XAMPP)

Tags: php, apache, firefox, localhost

This is a really strange thing. I 'uploaded' (ie, copied to htdocs) a php file but it's not running. I get the download dialog from Firefox to download it.

That is really weird. Although I can run the file in Chrome it wouldn't run in Firefox. What can be the problem.

I got the latest XAMPP version on Windows 7 64-bit.

Edit: typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I found out why it's not working in firefox. Chrome just prints what it gets but Firefox is doing it right i guess. I've written in the header to be an JSON object. It\'s an api so that is why. I was testing in firefox with firebug: header("Content-type: application/json");

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like PHP is not activated. Are you really sure the file is running in Chrome? I suspect not, but the `<?php ... ?>` part is hidden by the browser (view the source code in Chrome).

Comment: Yes it is running. I don't see any line of my code and it is requesting something from the database.

Comment: Maybe an old version is cached by Firefox? Empty the cache in Firefox. Also try download the file and check the contents (does it contain PHP code or is it the correct HTML document?).

Comment: What I get back is an empty file. An empty .php file when I download it

Comment: Try if the server is answering correctly by issuing your own HTTP request manually using telnet. This shows you exactly what is sent by the server, including HTTP headers.

Comment: Oke. I tried something else: 
<?php

echo 'test';

?>

And it returns test as it should

Comment: Then the problem is with your code. Check which HTTP headers you're sending, and also check messages in your PHP error log.

Comment: But it's pretty strange that Chrome does actually print something while Firefox doesn't

Comment: Oke, I found out why it's not working in firefox. Chrome just prints what it gets but Firefox is doing it right i guess. I've written in the header to be an JSON object. It\'s an api so that is why. I was testing in firefox with firebug: header("Content-type: application/json");